# Skipping rows in numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array `imgs_all` with `imgs_all.shape == (511,112,112,2)`. I also have another numpy array `NotMissed` with size 511rows, filled with 1s and 0s. How would I go about skipping the rows in `imgs_all` whenever `NotMissed` is zero?
I tried to do something like the following but I think I got it all wrong as I am not obtaining the result I want.

```
import numpy as np

N1 = SCALE - len(counter_missed) #number of rows that are not zero
imgs_all_new = np.zeros((N1,112,112,2), dtype = np.float32)

for zeros,goodimages in zip(NotMissed, imgs_all[:,:,:,:]):
     if zeros == 1:  
         imgs_all_new = goodimages
 print(imgs_all_new.shape)
```

Comment: Its as simple as "imgs_all[NotMissed==1]"

Comment: Of course!! That flew right by me did not even think about it. If you want to post it as an answer I will accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can slice the array with a boolean array:

```py
non_missing_imgs = NotMissed == 1
sum(non_missing_imgs) # how many True entries are there
>>> 279


imgs_all[non_missing_imgs].shape
>>> (279,112,112,2)
```